# Python web table scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here are the code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
'https://g10oal.com/match/964ba1d9-fa9b-4d48-8877-ff577a1ef7fe/odds'
]

all_data = []
for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    Container0 = soup.findAll("div", class_="team-name home-team")
    print(Container0)
    tables = soup.findAll("table", {"class": ["table", "table-sm", "odds-compare-table"]})
    for table in tables:

        for row in table.findAll('tr'):
            tds = [cell.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for cellin row.findAll(["td", "th"])]
            all_data.append(tds)
            print(*tds)
```

Expected Result: (in one line)
聖荷西地震 2.05 3.55 2.85 2.50 2.35 3.30 [-1] 3.60 3.95 1.67 1.92 [0/-0.5] 1.90 12 33.33% 2.20   3.50    2.60 2.60 2.35 3.15 4.10 4.05 1.57 2.05 [0/-0.5] 1.78 16 25.00% 馬會* 2.20    3.50    2.60    0.89    0.90    0.90    0.87

I am a new on python. I want to get first odds and last odds of each table. How can i change the code?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Above are the capture screen. My expected result should be printed out Row A to Row J in one line which i marked the A to J on the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the first and last rows of your tables in your tables for-loop you can add the following code:

```
allLines = table.findAll('tr')
wantedLines = allLines[len(allLines) - 1:]
wantedLines.append(allLines[:1])
```

Doing so in `wantedLine` you'll have only the first and last row that interest you. Now you can execute the code for extracting the odds

Comment: Thanks Giovanni. I need to put your code into which part? Below of "for table in tables:"?

Comment: Hi Alau yes exactly, Doing so you'll have in wanted lines, on each loop, the last and the first row (tr) of your table. If my answer help to solve you problem please highlight it.

Comment: I added the three code, but the result is not same my expected result.
my last print code => print(*tds,wantedLines). is it i need to correct something on it?

Comment: Honestly I don't quite understand what you really are expecting as an output. Can you provide more information? Like more data or screenshot where you highlight what you really want as your output. Thanks

Comment: Capture screen was uploaded. Hope you can understand my expected result.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get what you want, your expeceted result and the order of letters on your screenshots doesn't show the same data. And also doesn't seems a real pattern, why in the C point you want the very first line? It's not clear please explain bettere what do you want